# Compatiable angularjs-nvd3-directives.js version for nvd3 version 1.8.1

Tags: angularjs-nvd3-directives

I want to design multi-bar chart using nvd3 version 1.8.1 and angularjs-nvd3-directives.js. I found some problems with tooltip positioning with older versions of nvd3.So I want to use nvd3 version 1.8.1.

Then my question is: Which version of angularjs-nvd3-directives.js is Compatiable with nvd3 version 1.8.1?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: This question should be asked to the developer(s) of the plugin as it is not documented in their changelog. As you already posted the question there https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives/issues/351 the question here is inrelevant.

Comment: Here is the plunker link for the tooltip positioning problem in firefox:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rJCnPoq9hGHV9B3YO3DU?p=preview